# Capture Output of dscl Command for Backup Script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting, backup

I am currently managing a fleet of Macs that are being recycled so we need to figure out a way to automate a onetime backup of a user's folder (excluding any superfluous accounts like Shared or root) on the system to a network share using `rsync`.

I would like to capture the output of the result of each user using the following command:

```
$ dscl /Local/Default -list /Users UniqueID | awk '$2 >= 500 { print $1; }'
```

Example output:

```
John
Bob
```

I apologize if this is not the most elegant of solution or way to solve this problem (learning bash as I go). But what is the best way to parse the line-by-line results for both John and Bob (or some n-results), assign them a variable with the results to `\Users\$RESULT` and copy those contents over to `\Volumes\Backup\$RESULT+DATESTAMP`?

Ultimately, the goal is to basically create a backup of both `\Users\John` & `\Users\Bob` to `\Volumes\Backup\John-5/5/15` & `\Volumes\Backup\Bob-5/5/15` from pulling the results of the previous `dscl` command.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why aren't you just copying the directories in /Users instead of fiddling dscl?

Comment: We have all sorts of computers coming in with many different accounts and can heavily vary anywhere between 1 to 10+ users. I've thought of doing it individually as that would simplify things but would consume way too much time. That's why we wanted to figure out a way to automate all the backups of every user with a single one time click solution (a set it and forget it mentality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick, if I understand you correctly.

```
for name in $(dscl /Local/Default -list /Users UniqueID | awk '$2 >= 500 { print $1; }')
do
    cp -r /Users/$name /Volumes/Backup/$name-$(date +%d.%m.%y)
done
```

I assume you used \ to split directories by accident, don't you? Additionally, for obvious reasons, I switched from / to . in the date format.